# Deploying React + Express on Azure

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, express, deployment

I'm having that problem where I'm trying to deploy Express and React boilerplate app like one app on Azure App Services. Locally everything works normaly, but when I try to deploy the whole thing, I see ":( Application Error " screen. I think it has to do something with the way my "scripts" inside server's package.json are set...(deploying only express server without client files works just fine). Here I'm trying to let Azure execute the build command once the app is deployed and not before that:

"scripts": {
    "start": "cd client && npm run build && cd ../ && node server",
    "test": "echo something"
  },

Probably I'm missing something crucial for Azure (I'm a beginner).I've read a lot and followed many tutorials but nothing seems to solve my problem. I'll really appreciate it if someone can give me a hand. Thank you!

Link to my github repo : https://github.com/Ivailo663/finalExpressApp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"scripts": { "start": "cd client && npm run build && cd ../ && node server", "test": "echo something" }
```

This script will work if you already have all the modules your app needed, but if you don't have the modules, you need to install them first.

However, it is recommended that you build the client locally or use pipline to deploy the **build** folder to azure.

Comment: Can you give me some guidance of how to do that? I also read somewhere something about web.config file... getting even more confused now. @Tony Ju

Comment: @IvailoGeorgiev My suggestions is that you build the client locally. I don't think Azure will run npm install under client folder automatically.

Comment: Does that mean that the build folder should be uploaded into github? @Tony Ju

Comment: @IvailoGeorgiev Yes, I think so.

Comment: @IvailoGeorgiev If we need to deploy an angular app, we just put the files in build folder to wwwroot directory.

Comment: @IvailoGeorgiev Here is a video which show you how to create, build, and deploy your Angular app to Azure App Service using Azure Devops. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NFqrWsUPCAM&t=53s